# $Cookies not setting instant

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-cookies, angular-cookies

I am stuck at hiding and showing login/logout buttons at navbar. I am setting some cookies at `loginCtrl` belongs to `login.html`. And getting those cookies in `homeCtrl` which belongs to `home.html`. Here is my code;

```
.controller("loginCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $cookies, $state) {
    $scope.login = function () {
         Auth.$authWithPassword({}).then(function() {

             $rootScope.bekmez = true; // Using this in home.html > navbar.
             $cookies.put('Some', true);
             $state.go('baba.ana.manga');
})
.controller("homeCtrl", function($scope, $cookies) {

         $scope.bekmez = $cookies.get("Some");
)}
```

My navbar:

```
<li ng-show="bekmez">Username</li>
<li ng-hide="bekmez">Login Button</li>
```

So i did some googling and find that;

> Cookies are only added to the browser on digest.

I dont know what the digest is. So what is the possible solution to my problem?

Comment: I am sorry, but what is yours problem? You didn't mention it. Regarding code it looks ok. Everything what you can do with cookies(settings) is : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider

Comment: @Errorpo Problem is when i logged in login button stil shows up but when i refresh the page login button is gone. So cookie is in place no problem there but  problem occur because of saving the cookies happening after the `$rootScope.bekmez = true`.